# Can somebody give me a grammatical insight into the following very short sentence?

Tags: syntax, colloquial-language, particle-の, contractions

> 何してんの?

The translated meaning is "what are you doing?", but I am having difficulty understanding how the て form of する is referring to the present tense (I would have expected している here).

Also, I am not comfortable with the "ん", although I have seen it appear before.

Comment: As a Japanese-speaker, I felt the same way when I first heard an English-speaker say "Whatcha doin'?"